# Soap Client created from WSDL does not bind to all data declared in response for method, VS2017

Tags: .net, xml, web-services, soap, response

I have been asked to create an application in VB.NET that utilizes an External web service, they provided a WSDL which creates all necessary proxy, methods and classes, however it seems since this service runs on an IBM websphere server with J2EE that something is not working as designed for .NET, when i create instance of the service and call a method that uses a specific set of parameters and returns a specific complex type, some of the data is lost in .net, the XML response from the server contains all the correct data, it just is not available as part of the data in .net to process.

I have not been involved with soap for many years now, mostly i do web development and create webservices that are called using ajax so i am having difficulty figuring this one out, hope someone can provide me some direction.

This is what is returned from their server, the element named "**userArea**" is supposed to be present in the object declared as a response but it is not populated inside debugger or have any value (Not serialized).

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <upd:pricingAndAvailabilityResponse xmlns:upd="http://shopmanagement.service.ml.imc.com" xmlns:upd1="http://shopmanagement.datatypes.ml.imc.com">
      <upd1:freightCharge>0.00</upd1:freightCharge>
      <upd1:partPriceAvailability>
        <upd1:lineItemNumber>05</upd1:lineItemNumber>
        <upd1:lineCode>A1</upd1:lineCode>
        <upd1:mfgPartNumber>19-B7135NM</upd1:mfgPartNumber>
        <upd1:orderedAsNumber>19-B7135NM</upd1:orderedAsNumber>
        <upd1:qtyRequested>1</upd1:qtyRequested>
        <upd1:partDescription>CALIPER</upd1:partDescription>
        <upd1:brandOrManufacturer>A1 Cardone</upd1:brandOrManufacturer>
        <upd1:customerPrice>112.08</upd1:customerPrice>
        <upd1:listPrice>322.43</upd1:listPrice>
        <upd1:corePrice>69.0</upd1:corePrice>
        <upd1:timeZone>PST</upd1:timeZone>
        <upd1:flag>0</upd1:flag>
        <upd1:codeType>
          <upd1:message/>
        </upd1:codeType>
        <upd1:userArea>
          <upd1:branch>Phoenix Fillmore, AZ</upd1:branch>
          <upd1:availableQuantity>1</upd1:availableQuantity>
          <upd1:carrier>GROUND</upd1:carrier>
          <upd1:transitDays>GROUND 2 Business</upd1:transitDays>
          <upd1:freightCharge/>
        </upd1:userArea>
      </upd1:partPriceAvailability>
    </upd:pricingAndAvailabilityResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is the sample of the method called, it returns a type of declared as pricingAndAvailabilityResponse which is in their specifications, but part of it just disappear's in the response after loaded into the application, it is however contained in the XML the WSDL is supposed to bind i just don't know at this point how to gain access to it, any thoughts would be greatly appreciated since i am running into dead ends.

[sample of the method called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQEkX.jpg)

**Data returned to the response object, items circled are not populated but should be based on the XML.**

[Data returned to the response object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqkHn.png)

**The Webservice providers response was:**

The binding of the response to the client objects entirely depend on the client program and web service engine at the client side. For your reference we tried to consume the same web service using java and you can see in the below screenshot it is able to bind **userArea**. If your programming environment is not able to tie up the elements, the other approach for you could be parsing the response document in a handler and read DOM elements.

Please let us know in case any element in the response is not coming as per WSDL.

And below is a test they ran using JAVA but there must be something different about JAVA I would guess.

[below is a test they ran using JAVA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti8Px.png)

I ran SOAP validation as per suggestion and it came back as "**Schema Compliance Failed**" could this be related ? And if so how could it be corrected in VB.NET or can this only be fixed by the provider?

[Schema Compliance Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwZzr.png)

Comment: if the response is not as per wsdl , it breaks the contract of SOPA principle , it should be treated as invalid response , try and read about SOAP validation

Comment: I ran SOAP validation as per suggestion and it came back as "**Schema Compliance Failed**" could this be related ? And if so how could it be corrected in VB.NET or can this only be fixed by the provider?

Answer (score 0):

In the end the solution for me was to validate the XML using SOAPUI, it identified schema issues in the WSDL and after requesting the provider to send me a correct WSDL all is normal, I am guessing that the WSDL I received was probably the incorrect one since he had reported earlier that there was no other complaints regarding the Webservice, it only surfaced as a result of my new project involvement. Ashish's suggestion sent me in the right direction.